# My Tkinter button command only runs through the loop once

Tags: python, user-interface, for-loop, tkinter

I am writing an program for my job where I am working with the Smartsheet API.

Here is my code:

```
import smartsheet
import logging
from tkinter import *

token  = "API KEY HERE"
matt_workspace = 7813091611174788
ss_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token) #Matt's workspace  

ss_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

#for gethering workspaces

workspace_response = ss_client.Workspaces.list_workspaces(include_all=True)
all_workspaces = workspace_response.data
workspaces_name_and_id= []
for x in all_workspaces:
  workspaces_name_and_id.append(([str(x.name)], x.id))

selected_workspaces = []

def raise_frame(frame):
frame.tkraise()

#TODO set up UI root
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3

def set_selected_workspaces(listbox):
    for x in listbox.curselection():
        selected_workspaces.append(workspaces_name_and_id[x])
        return selected_workspaces

class WorkspacesPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Workspace Selection", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        wkdirections = tk.Label(self, 
            text = "1. Press the 'gather' button to gather all your available workspaces. \n 2. Select the workspaces with sheets you want to edit from the list. (Holding ctrl selects individual, holding shift selects en masse)")
        wkdirections.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=CENTER)

        WorkspaceList = Listbox(self, selectmode=EXTENDED, width=100, height=50)
        WorkspaceList.pack(side=LEFT)

        for x in workspaces_name_and_id:
            WorkspaceList.insert(END, (x))

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame("FoldersPage"), set_selected_workspaces(WorkspaceList) ,print(selected_workspaces)], padx=20, pady=3)
        button.place(relx=0.975, rely=0.975, anchor=SE)
```

I removed two classes from this code  I included that are not necessary (too keep it less messy than it already is (including the main App/Tk app)).

My problem is with the set_selected_workplaces function in the "Next" button on my "Workspace Selection" page.

Right now it is populating my list box with workspaces and their respective ID's. Then when I click next, I want it to loop through the selected workspaces in the listbox, and add it to my list "selected_workspaces" for use later in my program.

The problem is that when I click this, it is only adding the first selection in my listbox, thus leading me to believe its only going through the first loop in my for loop.

Any suggestions? Please go easy on me, I'm decently new at coding and I'm sure its a mess. If you need any clarification or more insight, please let me know, I'm baffled.

Comment: This would be easier to debug if you created a proper function rather than trying to cram a bunch of code into a lambda.

Comment: Three functions in a lambda is two too many, and I would argue it's three too many. In this case there's simply no good reason to use `lambda`.

Comment: can you explain further? I am new so, in my eyes, I don't see why it's bad since it servers my purpose (which is a program that just needs to work, doesn't need to be pretty)

Comment: If your only goal is "it works", then it's fine. It's a bit like creating a table with a wobbly leg, though. But sometimes, a table with a wobbly leg is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are returning too early. Instead of this

```
def set_selected_workspaces(listbox):
    for x in listbox.curselection():
        selected_workspaces.append(workspaces_name_and_id[x])
        return selected_workspaces
```

try this

```
def set_selected_workspaces(listbox):
    for x in listbox.curselection():
        selected_workspaces.append(workspaces_name_and_id[x])
    return selected_workspaces
```

Your loop will return on the first iteration, which I don't believe is what you want.

Comment: It was my pleasure. I've certainly been helped plenty on this site.